# Java - How should I remove the error from the code so that the image can be thresholded?

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.Color;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
public class Thresholdst {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int THRESHOLD = 111;
        String filename = args[0];
        Picture f = new Picture("C:\\Users\\User\\eclipse-workspace\\breakvisualcaptcha\\src\\breakvisualcaptcha\\2.png");
        f.show();
        for (int i = 0; i < f.width(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < f.height(); j++) {
                Color color = f.get(i, j);
                double lum = Luminance.intensity(color);
                if (lum >= THRESHOLD) f.set(i, j, Color.WHITE);
                else                  f.set(i, j, Color.BLACK);
            }
        }
        f.show();
    }
 }
```

I am getting the error on the line:

```
Picture f = new Picture ("C:\\Users\\User\\eclipse-workspace\\breakvisualcaptcha\\src\\breakvisualcaptcha\\2.png");
```

Eclipse says:

> Picture cannot be resolved to a type

I am using the header file `import javax.imageio.ImageIO;` then all the other lines following the `File f` line are getting highlighted. Please help me.

Comment: please add the error stack trace

Comment: File class is used as an alternative for Picture pic = new Picture(...);

Comment: you edited your question and we get **where** the error is. But **what** is the error?

Comment: The line is getting highlighted in red and this is the reason why I am not able to run the code. As far as I understand there is a header file which I am missing but what is the way out as if I try to include a header file in order to remove this error, more errors arise due to the addition of the header file. What is a good solution to the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Eclipse is saying "Picture cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: you have to add `Picture` to your imported class

Comment: How can this be added? Kindly help me as I am still in learning stage.

Comment: Picture isn't a class from the standard jdk. Where is it from?

Comment: It is an external class not present in the standard jdk. I referred this link in order to get the code.https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/31datatype/Threshold.java.html

Comment: Okay, then you have to download the source code so you can include Picture in your project.

Comment: Or maybe they have a compiled version that you can download. Either way you need a Picture class.

Comment: https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/

Comment: How should I do it, should I copy the code in the same package and use it in a different class or use it as a .jar file but the jar file is not present only the source code is.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. It worked. However I am getting a new error which appears when I run the program. It says :                                                             
 " Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at breakvisualcaptcha.Thresholdst.main(Thresholdst.java:13)".